# Solutions of $x^2 = x + 1$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

In a stage preceding the national stage of the math olympiad in Romania ( which was held online because of the pandemic ) the following question was asked:

If $A$ is the set of natural numbers $n$ for which $x^2=x+1$ has only a solution in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ then:

A) $A$ has no elements

B) $A$ has only one element

C) The elements of $A$ are even

D) $A$ has infinitely many elements

E) ( I can't remember it ).

The oficial answer was that $A$ has only one element but when I wrote a bit of code I found $5$, $46985$, $47209$ and more to be in $A$.

Can you help me characterise the numbers in $A$ a little bit more?

Edit: [image: The code]

Comment: Are you sure that $46985$ and $47209$ indeed work? I can't seem to replicate it.

Comment: I added a photo of the code. It seems right to me but maybe I'm dumb

Comment: Here's just some observation, maybe someone can add something to this end. $n\in A$ if and only if $\mathbb Z_n$ contains an element $x$ whose inverse is $x+1$.

Comment: It's possible that overflow happened for 46985, etc. (the square was too big so it was rounded by some large number)

Comment: It seems like that is the case (so I am indeed dumb) but I still can't figure out why only $5$ is in $A$

Comment: When you say “only a solution” do you mean “only one solution?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n=p_1^{r_1}\ldots p_m^{r_m}$ then by Chinese Remainder theorem, the solution is unique $\pmod n\iff$ unique $\pmod{p_i^{r_i}}$ for every $i$. This in particular implies the solution is unique $\pmod{p_i}$.

First, we do the case when $n=p$ is prime. Obviously $p=2$ doesn't work. For other cases, we are now in a field with characteristic not $2$, so we can use the quadratic formula (being in a field guarantees we can factor into two linear factors; characteristic not 2 guarantees we can divide by 2). If there were to be a solution, the discriminant $\Delta=5$ must be a square. For it to be unique, $\frac{1+\sqrt5}2=\frac{1-\sqrt5}2$ (for a chosen square root of $5$), or equivalently $\sqrt5=0$. Hence $5=0$, and $p=5$. We check that $5$ indeed works.

Back to the original case: the prime case implies $n=5^m$ for some $m\geq1$ (since it can have no prime factor other than 5). But when $n=25$ there is already no solution (and if $m\geq 2$, a solution $\pmod{5^m}$ would give rise to a solution $\pmod{25}$, a contradiction) so $n=5$.

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is a solution, then so is $1-m.$ (Why?)

So if $m$ is unique, then $1-m\equiv m\pmod n.$ So $n$ must be odd, and thus $$m\equiv \frac{n+1}2\pmod n.$$

So $$\frac{(n+1)^2}4\equiv \frac{n+1}2+1\pmod n$$

Multiplying by $4,$ we get:

$$(n+1)^2\equiv 2(n+1)+4\pmod n$$

Which is equivalent to:

$$0\equiv n^2\equiv 5\pmod n$$